# Procedures with linked server with strange error

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have two procedures that uses the same linked server,one works and one doens't, when i execute they directly in the DB both Works normal but in the cs just one Works.

The proc that Works is that

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_WKF_INS_ANEXO]   


    @ID_PROCESSOITEM    INT,
    @DOCUMENTO          VARBINARY(MAX) = null,
    @DOCUMENTONOME      VARCHAR(200)   = null,
    @DOCUMENTOTIPO      VARCHAR(200)   = null,
    @COD_FUNC           INT

AS     
BEGIN   
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    INSERT INTO [WorkFlow].[dbo].[WKF_ProcessoAnexo]   
    (   
        Id_ProcessoItem,
        Id_ProcessoDetalhe,
        Doc_Anexo,
        Des_DocNome,
        Des_DocTipo,
        Cod_Func,
        Dt_Inclusao,
        Dt_Alteracao
    )   
    VALUES   
    (   
        @ID_PROCESSOITEM,
        null,
        @DOCUMENTO,
        @DOCUMENTONOME,
        @DOCUMENTOTIPO,
        @COD_FUNC, 
        GetDate(),
        Null
    )


END
```

And i use it this way.

```
public static void spItnInsAnexo(this dbContext db, int idProcessoItem, byte[] documento, string documentoNome,string documentoTipo,int codigoFuncionario)
        {
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
               "[BRZGRUAP17].[WorkFlow].[dbo].[SP_WKF_INS_ANEXO] @ID_PROCESSOITEM, @DOCUMENTO,@DOCUMENTONOME,@DOCUMENTOTIPO,@COD_FUNC",
                new SqlParameter("@ID_PROCESSOITEM", idProcessoItem),
                new SqlParameter("@DOCUMENTO", documento),
                new SqlParameter("@DOCUMENTONOME", documentoNome),
                new SqlParameter("@DOCUMENTOTIPO", documentoTipo),
                new SqlParameter("@COD_FUNC", codigoFuncionario)
            );
        }
```

The one that doesn't work is the next one,i pass the parameters correct but i cant find why it doens't work,when i execute it does not give any error,but it don't update in the DB.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_WKF_UPD_ITENS]   



    @ID_REFERENCIA VARCHAR(30),
    @ID_PROCESSOITEM INT

 AS   




BEGIN   

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    UPDATE [WorkFlow].[dbo].[WKF_ProcessoItem] SET
    Id_Referencia = @ID_REFERENCIA
    where Id_ProcessoItem = @Id_ProcessoItem


END
```

And this is how i call it.It uses the same way i use in the other one that Works,i cant find why it doesnt work,if i use the same idProcessoItem and IdReferencia in the db and update normally.Someone knows what i'm missing?

```
public static void spItnUpdItens(this dbContext db, int idProcessoItem,string IdReferencia)
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
           "[BRZGRUAP17].[WorkFlow].[dbo].[SP_WKF_UPD_ITENS] @ID_PROCESSOITEM, @ID_REFERENCIA",
            new SqlParameter("ID_PROCESSOITEM", idProcessoItem),
            new SqlParameter("ID_REFERENCIA", IdReferencia)
        );
    }
```

Comment: What are the symptoms of it not working?

Comment: Note in the failing call you have the order of params reversed (i.e. `@ID_REFERENCIA` is not the first one)

Comment: Maybe its the reversed,going to test now

Comment: That was it,I thought that if i'm passing the names the DB could localize based on that,but i was wrong,thanks Alex.